# Finding missing mouse clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, mouse

I am working with a C# WinForms application which I'm not very familiar with.  The control is intended to be draggable, and indeed it is draggable if the user starts the drag in parts of the control, but not in others.

The control contains several child controls, and it's my belief that some of these child controls are capturing the mouse clicks before the parent control sees them, hence the failure in certain areas.  I have confirmed in the debugger that the mouse-down handler for the parent is only invoked when the user clicks on particular child controls.

Given I know the clicks are being captured/suppressed before they get to my handler, is there a way in the debugger (or otherwise) to determine where the clicks ARE going?  Staring at the code has not been successful because I don't know where to start.

Comment: I believe that if you enable the KeyPreview property on the parent control then you will catch the events before the child controls do. Not too sure though.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like KeyPreview only works for key presses, not mouse events.

Answer (score 4):

Bundled with Visual Studio comes a niftly little program called [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). It allows you to [log all messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265737%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) being sent to windows, and shows you the 'real' structure of Win32 controls within your window (many controls are not actually controls but just custom painted screen areas). You should be able, with some inspection, to find the culprit with the message log.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I need!  It does identify all the controls, and detects the events, but it's telling me that all the mouse events go to the top level window (several levels above the control I'm interested in).  So I can't see within the form which handler is being invoked for a particular mouse press.

Comment: That's how Windows works actually - all messages are sent to the top level window, and then distributed down with `DispatchMessage` Win32 API function. As such you should be able to preview most if not all messages by overriding the `Control.WndProc` method in your Form instance. For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx

Comment: Overriding Control.WndProc will allow me to see where messages are coming from, but not where DispatchMessage will send them, which is what I'm interested in.  As before, there's no problem with the messages coming in from Windows, it's where they go then that I need to understand.

Comment: You can find some hardcore explanation of how to dive deeper at http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html. It shows how to retrieve the handle of the target window (ie. replace `DispatchMessage`), and from there a call to `GetWindowInfo` should give most other info. I don't think you can do all this in managed C# though, pretty sure you need some unsafe imports there hehe.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to fix the issue through staring at the code in the end, but I'll use this next time it comes up, as I'm sure it will!